# I'm having issues getting the NZ function working in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to tie a description to group codes to use in another table. Unfortunately the data is from a very old database and didn't have very good requirements for fields when it was initially created. So now I have a number of fields for part number group codes that were blank. I'm trying to convert these null values to say "blank". I've tried this many different ways and cannot get the nz function to modify the data in any way.

In the provided code snippet I have tried using the nz function only after select, only after from, and in both places as shown.

```
SELECT [Part Numbers].Part, nz([Part Numbers].Group,"Blank"), [Group Codes].Description
FROM [Part Numbers] 
INNER JOIN [Group Codes] ON nz([Part Numbers].[Group],"Blank") = [Group Codes].[Group Code];
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it is completely leaving blank values out of the query, so I have also tried this with LEFT JOIN in order to bring those in to no avail.

Comment: What does "cannot get" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Are you sure fields are null and not empty string?

Comment: Are you saving [Group Codes] autonumber key into [Part Numbers] or a text value from [Group Code]?

Comment: @June7 I'm pretty sure they're null. I'm not 100% how to check though as the group codes are alpha-numeric. Cannot get means that it was just completely excluding the null cells from the query. They didn't exist when I ran it. And [Group Codes].[Group Code] is related to [Part Numbers].[Group] in my relationship tree if that is what you are asking with the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query doesn't return records where Group field is Null. It can't even be displayed in query design with that join.

Consider RIGHT JOIN:

```
SELECT [Part Numbers].Part, Nz([Part Numbers].Group,"Blank") AS Expr1, [Group Codes].Description
FROM [Group Codes] RIGHT JOIN [Part Numbers] ON [Group Codes].[Group Code] = [Part Numbers].Group;
```

Comment: this didn't work how I need. I'm not exactly sure why though. The part numbers table has 51419 fields that all have some sort of entry in the [Part Numbers].Group field or that field is null. The [Group Codes].Group field only has entries that exist in the [Part numbers].Group field. However, with the RIGHT JOIN somehow I ended up with 51422 entries.

Comment: Check for Null by building a query with an expression: `Group IS NULL` returns true if Null, false if not. Then there must be several duplicates in [Group Codes]. To check this, do a query that counts `SELECT [Group Code], Count{*) AS Cnt FROM [Group Codes] GROUP BY [Group Code] HAVING Count(*) >1;`.

Comment: They are apparently not null values, although I'm not sure how. They export from another SQL table and are most certainly null exporting from there, but when importing here they apparently lose that. As far as the [Group Codes] there are no duplicates in that table.

Comment: Then I don't know why record count is off.